# What is the XML format corresponding to java.util.Map?

Tags: java, xml, apache, http, post

I am using Apache HTTPClient in order to make an HTTP POST operation. The request XML should correspond to a java.util.Map.

Eg :-

```
Map<String, Employee> employeeRecords = new HashMap<String, Employee>();
map.add("xyz", new Employee());
map.add("xyz", new Employee());
```

I want to create an XML that represents "employeeRecords" map so that I cane use it further as the "RequestEntity" for HTTP POST operation. Any idea what should be the format of such XML ?

Comment: In your example, you are overwriting the "xyz" key, so your map as listed contains a single item.

Comment: Also, the format of the POSTed XML is an API constraint / specification.  Whoever published the API should tell you what the XML should look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use XML APIs to convert it into XML.